# Rusted tapcons on an aluminum screen patio cage

Tags: screws

What replacement screw is best to replace rusted tapcons on an aluminum screen patio cage?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a picture?

Comment: "Tapcon" is a brand name for a type of concrete screw.  It doesn't sound like that's what you mean?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information to help you. Please take our tour to learn more.